# Code cannot calculate percentage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Thanks for all the answers, it really helped me out!

But I have run into a new problem... In the program I am writing the user is asked to type in answers to different math questions, and the console will after each question say if the answers are correct or incorrect. And at the end the program will display how many of the users answers was correct in percentage, this is were I am running into the problem.

```
Console.Write("How many questions would you like to answer (Maximum value is '100'): ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int questionsAmount = int.Parse(input);

        int correctAnswers = 0;
        int IncorrectAnswers = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= questionsAmount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===================");
            Console.WriteLine("Question " + i);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndNumber = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            int rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            Console.Write("What equals " + rndNumber + " + " + rndNumber2 + " = ");
            string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int answer = int.Parse(input2);

            if (answer == rndNumber + rndNumber2)
            {
                correctAnswers++;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer correct.");
                Console.WriteLine("Correct answers: " + correctAnswers);
            }
            else
            {
                IncorrectAnswers++;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer incorrect.");
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect answers: " + IncorrectAnswers);
            }
        }
        double percentage = correctAnswers / questionsAmount * 100;
        Console.WriteLine(percentage + "% of your answers was correct");
```

As you see, once all the questions have been answered it will calculate the percentage, but since I have assigned the variable 'correctAnswers' to the value '0', the calculation will look like this: 0 / x * 100 = 0

If I put the variables 'correctAnswers' and 'incorrectAnswers' within the `for-statement` the line `double percentage = correctAnswers / questionsAmount * 100;` would not work.

Comment: The `try-catch` is fine, it's your loop logic that isn't

Comment: Exception handling can be a lot worse than using `goto`.  It is here, you completely lost track of the program flow and no longer understand how your program works.  Handling an exception should be exceptional, there is nothing particularly exceptional about the user entering wrong data.  So don't use exceptions, use `int.TryParse()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch clause will only execute if an exception is thrown. What you want is to put the "incorrect answer" logic in an ordinary `else` clause.

```
  while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("What equals " + rndNumber1 + " + " 
                          + rndNumber2 + ": ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int answer = int.Parse(input);

            if (answer == rndNumber1 + rndNumber2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect. Try again.");
               Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, something went wrong.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me. Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an `else` block, not a `catch` block:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("What equals " + rndNumber1 + " + " + rndNumber2 + ": ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int answer = int.Parse(input);

    if (answer == rndNumber1 + rndNumber2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect. Try again.");
    }
}
```

Try/catch is for handling *exceptions*, not application logic.  `if` pairs with `else`, not with `catch`.

For example, if you try to `int.Parse()` a value which isn't an integer (such as a string of letters) then *that* will throw an exception, and you can handle *that* in a `catch` block.  (Or use `int.TryParse()` to avoid the exception.)

Answer (score 1):

Place the sections of code that might throw exceptions in a try block and place code that handles exceptions in a catch block. The catch block is a series of statements beginning with the keyword catch, followed by an exception type and an action to be taken.
You can output the "wrong answer" prompt in the else part as shown below.
Try and catch statemnts are for execution of lines of code exception.What you are testing is not an exception in code execution.It is just a variable that is not equal to another.

```
 {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            int rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("What equals " + rndNumber1 + " + " + rndNumber2 + ": ");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    int answer = int.Parse(input);

                    if (answer == rndNumber1 + rndNumber2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct.");
                        break;
                    }else{
     Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect. Try again.");
    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`try...catch` control block is used to handle exeptions, that means the code will jump to the `cath` part when an unexpected error is encountred.
In your code this part `Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct.");` will only be executed if a runtime error is thrown eg. `int.Parse()` is unable to parse the value.

When you are trying to compare values you should use the `if` flow structure

```
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(1, 100);
    int rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(1, 100);

    while (true)
    {
            Console.Write("What equals " + rndNumber1 + " + " + rndNumber2 + ": ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int answer = int.Parse(input);

            if (answer == rndNumber1 + rndNumber2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect. Try again.");
            }
    }
}
```